# Is there an npm library that uses best practices to scaffold a wordpress plugin that is build with React?

Tags: plugins

I am getting ready to create a new WordPress plugin and I would like to use React to build the plugin.  Is there any type of library that will scaffold the library and set up the webpack, babel, etc similar to what @wordpress/create-block does?